# Removing elements from Properties

Tags: java, properties

In order to avoid [ConcurrentModificationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html), i am resorting to the following:

```
        List<String> tobeRemoved = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (Object propertyKey : suppliedContent.keySet()) {
            key = (String) propertyKey;

            if (EqualityUtils.isMatching(rgx, key)) {
                tobeRemoved.add(key);
            }
        }

        for (String o : tobeRemoved) {
            suppliedContent.remove(o);
        }
```

Is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think using `iterator` and call `remove()` on `iterator` when matching would do same.

```
Iterator<String> supplieIter  = suppliedContent.keySet().iterator();

    while(supplieIter.hasNext()){
        key = supplieIter.next();

        if (EqualityUtils.isMatching(rgx, key)) {
           supplieIter.remove()
        }
    }
```

EDIT: Hand typed code. There may be syntax errors.

Comment: Can you please provide an example?

Comment: http://tech.puredanger.com/2009/02/02/java-concurrency-bugs-concurrentmodificationexception/

Answer (score 2):

You can use an Iterator.remove() like

```
Properties suppliedContent = ...
for (Iterator iter = suppliedContent.keySet().iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) 
    if (EqualityUtils.isMatching(rgx, (String) iter.next())) 
        iter.remove();
```

Comment: Thank you Peter. As always, great answer and example